# Regarding Stop blinking in flash Action Script

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Hi i am using flash Action Script. Image is displaying from internet at 1 sec interval. But this is blinking. How can i stop blinking so that i can see images continuously.

```
    var my_pb:mx.controls.ProgressBar;
my_pb.mode = "manual";
this.createEmptyMovieClip("img_mc", 999);
var my_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var mclListener:Object = new Object();
mclListener.onLoadStart = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {
    my_pb.label = "loading: "+target_mc._name;
};
mclListener.onLoadProgress = function(target_mc:MovieClip, numBytesLoaded:Number, numBytesTotal:Number) {
    var pctLoaded:Number = Math.ceil(100*(numBytesLoaded/numBytesTotal));
    my_pb.setProgress(numBytesLoaded, numBytesTotal);
};
var myInterval = setInterval(testInterval, 1000);
function testInterval() {
    my_mcl.addListener(mclListener);
    my_mcl.loadClip("https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2015/holi-festival-2015-5124794139803648-hp.gif", img_mc);
    //my_mcl.loadClip("https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2015/holi-festival-2015-5124794139803648-hp.gif", img_mc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid that you can use two MovieClips and every time load your image into one of them and hide the other one, like this :

```
var images:Array = [
    'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inficons/128/stackoverflow.png',
    'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inficons/128/joomla.png',
    'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inficons/128/bitcoin.png',
    'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inficons/128/wordpress.png',    
    'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inficons/128/github.png'
];  

var current_loader:Number = 1;
var current_img:Number = 0;

var progress_bar:mx.controls.ProgressBar;
    progress_bar.mode = 'manual';

this.createEmptyMovieClip('img_01', 999);
this.createEmptyMovieClip('img_02', 998);

img_01._x = img_01._y = img_02._x = img_02._y = 20;

var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();

var listener:Object = new Object();
    listener.onLoadStart = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {
        progress_bar.visible = true;
    }
    listener.onLoadProgress = function(target_mc:MovieClip, numBytesLoaded:Number, numBytesTotal:Number) {
        progress_bar.setProgress(numBytesLoaded, numBytesTotal);
    }
    listener.onLoadComplete = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {
        // hide the last image loader 
        if(target_mc._name == 'img_01'){
            img_02._visible = false;
        } else {
            img_01._visible = false;
        }
        // init the progress bar and hide it
        progress_bar.setProgress(0, 100);
        progress_bar.visible = false;
    }

var interval:Number = setInterval(load_image, 1000);
function load_image() { 
    loader.addListener(listener);
    loader.loadClip(images[current_img], _root['img_0'+current_loader]);
    // set the next loader
    current_loader = current_loader == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    // set next image
    current_img = current_img == images.length - 1 ? 0 : current_img + 1;
}
// load the first image 
load_image();
```

You can see this code working [here](http://www.fastswf.com/9-NoOgg).

Sometimes, we can not see the progress bar because image is loaded very fast, of course if you want to use large images, you have to increase your interval.

Hope that can help.