# how can i use setInterval to run it frequently in as 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2

I  have a loader componet and progressbar. I want it fetch image continously.
So I am try to Put a `setInterval`, but it does not works.

```
 var my_ldr:mx.controls.Loader;        
 var my_pb:mx.controls.ProgressBar;            
 var listener:Object = new Object();         
 my_pb.source = my_ldr;
 my_ldr.autoLoad = true;
 var interval:Number = setInterval(load_image, 2000);
 function load_image() {
   my_ldr.contentPath = ("http://google.example.image.php");
 }
 my_ldr.load(); 

 How can I use Timer to recieve Image  frequently ?
 thanks you
```

Comment: it only receive  one image.. I want it receive continously manner

Comment: I think that you have to use two Loaders, take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28912980/2256820).

Comment: i have seen...but...i  am searching for a small with effective program

Comment: What you mean ? It's the same "problem" with the same solution, you have just to copy the code and test it ;)

Comment: yes.... here what are the both loader name           CAN THIS WRITTEN IN AS 3.0 easily than 2.0

Comment: The problem is not because you are using AS2, it's just there is always some time between loading the image and showing it, so you will get the same behavior with AS3.

Comment: what are the loaders name  you have given....??  how can i add background color to it  ???

Comment: When I said two loaders, I meant two images ( the target MovieClips ).

Comment: some how it flickers... so i want to add a gif  file .....which is showing at the time of flicker ..... so give me some idea ... about this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to update the Loader as well as just the content path on interval. So you will need to add the my_ldr.load() inside the load_image function, I think.

Comment: Check to see if the image has changed somehow? You could have a check to see if the image is the same as the current one (either in your code or online). An alternative would be to use 2 loaders and just switch them out every second, updating one and then the other and hiding them after a second.

Comment: You would have the same problem and probably produce the same outcome. There are different methods but this is probably the easiest honestly.

Comment: some how it flickers... so i want to add a gif  file .....which is showing at the time of flicker ..... so give me some idea ... about this.....